# winrt::fire_and_forget, What does this do?

Tags: c++-winrt, c++-coroutine

I' m porting C++/CX application to C++/WinRT Core Application.

and I found a useful sample code (Simple3DGameDX) at this link.

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Simple3DGameDX/cppwinrt

and its Suspending method's return type is winrt::fire_and_forget.
but anther example in C++/CX, its Suspending method's return type is void.

why this return type is not void in C++/WinRT?
and What does this do?

C++/WinRT

```
winrt::fire_and_forget OnSuspending(IInspectable const& /* sender */, SuspendingEventArgs const& args)
```

C++/CX

```
void OnSuspending(Object^ Sender, SuspendingEventArgs^ Args)
```

Comment: In case you are familiar with C#, fire_and_forget is like "async void" in C# as the return type. The method does not return a Task but you can "await..." inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why this return type is not void in C++/WinRT? and What does this do?

Apart from documentation for [Fire and forget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#fire-and-forget), note the following: the function itself uses [`co_await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/await-enable-coroutine-support?view=msvc-160) operator in its body.

This requires that the function itself is coroutine friendly and could be compiled into "stackless" form, for asynchronous execution. `void` return type does not work out, but `fire_and_forget` struct is okay because C++/WinRT defines coroutine handling for it, as explained by the documentation.

Think of this as `void` which can be asynchronous and has no need to be waited on.

Answer (score 0):

> winrt::fire_and_forget, What does this do?

Please refer document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#fire-and-forget),

*Sometimes, you have a task that can be done concurrently with other work, and you don't need to wait for that task to complete (no other work depends on it), nor do you need it to return a value. In that case, you can fire off the task and forget it. You can do that by writing a coroutine whose return type is [**winrt::fire_and_forget**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/fire-and-forget) (instead of one of the Windows Runtime asynchronous operation types, or concurrency::task).*